# Space validation in react using react formik

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, formik, yup

index.js

```js
<div className="form-group">
  <label htmlFor='product_name'>Product Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="product_name" placeholder="Enter Product Name" className="form-control"
    onChange={formik.handleChange} onBlur={formik.handleBlur} />
  {
    formik.touched.product_name && formik.errors.product_name && formik.values.product_name.length > 0 ? (
      <div className='error'>{formik.errors.product_name}</div>) : null
  }
</div>
```

I am using formik with react for validation but when I enter space it validates the form but I want if there is only space it does not validate until there is some text. Can anyone help me out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Yup.string().trim()`:

```
import * as Yup from "yup";
import React from "react";
import { Form, Formik } from "formik";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ product_name: "" }}
      onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}
      validationSchema={Yup.object({
        product_name: Yup.string().trim().required()
      })}
    >
      {(formik) => (
        <Form>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="product_name">Product Name:</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="product_name"
              placeholder="Enter Product Name"
              className="form-control"
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
            />
            {formik.touched.product_name && formik.errors.product_name ? (
              <div className="error">{formik.errors.product_name}</div>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-smoke-ctzvz?file=/src/App.js:0-1050

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
  {
    formik.touched.product_name && formik.errors.product_name && formik.values.product_name.trim().length > 0 && formik.values.product_name.length > 0 ? (
      <div className='error'>{formik.errors.product_name}</div>) : null
  }
```

Where this ought to solve your issue: `formik.values.product_name.trim().length > 0`

Comment: The form will still submit though. This will just hide the error when `product_name` has no non-space characters. Unless I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue using Formik + Yup, they work pretty well together. I used Regex to check if the user's input matches with the expected input

```
import {Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage} from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  productName: Yup
    .string()
    .matches(/^\S*$/, "Name without spaces")
    // .matches(/^\w*$/, "Name without special chars")  -> if you don't want special chars
})

const CommonForm = () => {
  return (
    <Formik
    initialValues={{
      productName: ""
    }}
    validationSchema={ validationSchema }
    onSubmit={(values) => {
      // handle submit
      console.log(values)
    }}
    >
      <>
        <h1>FORM</h1>
        <Form>
          <label>Product name</label>
          <Field type="text" name="productName" />
          <ErrorMessage name="productName" />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      </>
    </Formik>
  )
};

export default CommonForm;
```